# Approximation of a $W^{1,2}(\Omega,\mathbb{S}^2)$ function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded domain with smooth boundary and $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega,\mathbb{S}^2)$ such that $|u|=1$ a.e. in $\Omega$. It is known that there is a sequence $u_n \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,2}$ norm.

Is it possible to find such a sequence with $|u_n|=1$ for all $n$ in $\Omega$ (or just $|u_n|=1$ on $\partial \Omega$)?

I found that the construction of such sequence is the use of mollifier but I can't figure out how to make $u_n$ satisfies $|u_n|=1$.

Also, I have tried to show that $u_n/|u_n|$ converges to $u$ in $W^{1,2}$ norm, but not success.
Thank you!

Comment: You can find some ideas in this paper: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00747679/document
See also: https://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/Sobolev%20mappings%20between%20metric%20spaces3.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much! So I think my statement is true according to Theorem 2.4 in the second paper?